# When did Germany begin to store it's gold deposits abroad?

Tags: germany, political-history, banking, money

I just learned from [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17416/does-germany-want-their-gold-back?newsletter=1&nlcode=85899%7C2bbd) that Germany is storing it's gold reserves around the globe.

When did this practice start? What was occurring at that time that drove the decision?

And an optional speculative question: what political goals could be driving the request to fetch the gold back?

Comment: Why do you assume it's more protected because it's inside the country? Anyway, this is not about history in any way, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro, you are correct. Now I notice there is a [politics SE](http://politics.stackexchange.com/). I'll request a move to that site.

Comment: @LennartRegebro is correct to question both ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Politics.SE, as stated by the OP.

Comment: I agree the question should be closed. But the answer is simple, along the lines of what Lennart Regebro has mentioned: In all matters of importance, one must avoid a single point of failure that can put you out of business. That is the basis for the idea of distributed processing models in IT and it is applicable across the board. In short: **Don't put all your eggs in one basket.**

Comment: People, this close comment is crazy. [Here](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1890/why-would-a-country-ever-store-its-gold-deposits-abroad) is the same question on Politics.SE. I am reluctant to delete this one, as the one answer is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

There may be differnet reasons.

An extract from the [German Wikipedia article about German gold reserves](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Goldreserven):

> Die Bundesbank hatte das Edelmetall an den führenden Goldhandelsplätzen New York, London und Paris gekauft und dort belassen

Germany (or better the Bundesbank) bought the gold at the leading markets (NY, London, Paris) and never transported it away. Just imagine the problems of a safe transport of the gold.

Another topic: There are about 500.000 Euro costs to deposit it at the Bank of England. In USA and France it is free. Maybe it is cheaper to store it abroad?

And the last reason: Why do you think it is more protected at home? During WWII Germany conquered big parts of Europe and there where different [Governments in exile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_in_exile). With gold abroad they still had access to there gold. The gold inside would be a capture of the conquerer. It is always a good idea to split the risk.

---

For your speculative question:
There were doubts, if the gold is still available. So let's bring it home ;)